# Assigning to RadioGroup Tag from Form Tag in XE8 causes access violation

Tags: forms, delphi, access-violation, delphi-xe8

I have recently upgraded from XE4 to XE8 and have come across a access violation when assigning a itemindex to a radio group. I was curious why in XE4 this works and XE8 it doesn't. All of the forms have been created when the main program starts up. This code works fine when debugging but when running as a standalone it throws the exception.

```
with TravelBookingForm do begin
   try
      rg1.itemindex:=tag-1;//not sure which causes the access violation
   except
      on E : Exception do
      begin
         showMessage(E.Message); //access violation message is shown
      end;
      rg1.tag := 0;
   end;
end;
```

NB: I have omitted code that isn't relevent

Comment: Get rid of the with statement and then debug it.  Confirm TravelBookingForm <> nil and rg1 <> nil - although if TravelBookingForm is the parent of rg1, I'm guessing TravelBookingForm hasn't been created

Comment: And if you are not sure whether the AV is coming from the `ItemIndex` assignment or the `Tag` reading, split them into separate statements.  Read the `Tag` into a local variable, then assign that to the `ItemIndex`.

Comment: In the project source code we have:
Application.CreateForm(TTravelBookingForm, TravelBookingForm);
so l think its being created

Comment: If you placed a breakpoint on the with statement and checked, you would know (or not) that it's being created.  It would take the guess work out of it

Comment: So after more testing I can confirm that rg1 is not nil and that it is the item causing the access violation

Comment: Try this: t:=TravelBookingForm.Tag; TravelBookingForm.rg1.ItemIndex:=t-1; where t is a local variable of type NativeInt. Verify that TravelBookingForm <> NIL and TravelBookingForm.rg1 <> NIL (I assume that rg1 is a member of TravelBookingForm - it's hard to see as you are using a WITH statement).

Comment: Which framework you are using VCL or FMX?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So after more testing I can confirm that rg1 is not nil and that it is the item causing the access violation.

If `rg1` is not `nil` and yet leads to an access violation then the most plausible explanation is that `rg1` points to memory that has been freed. This matches the observation that the error occurs sometimes (outside debugger) and not others (under debugger).

So, your program is destroying the form at some point, and then later referring to the form.

Clearly that is an error in your program and you will need to make sure that you never refer to forms after they have been destroyed. Unfortunately the IDE encourages you to create all your forms once at startup, and hold references in global variables. This makes it all too easy to have stale references.

If you used the full debug version of FastMM then that tool would be able to warn you when you attempt to access memory that has been freed.

Comment: I have tried creating a local version of the form:
TravelBookingForm : TTravelBookingForm;
TravelBookingForm := TTravelBookingForm.Create(main);
and using that but we still get the same access violation?

Comment: Also tried Application.createForm(TTravelBookingForm, TravelBookingForm); with the same results

Comment: I can't find anyway that we free it, using
TravelBookingForm.free
TravelBookingForm.destroy
freeandnil(TravelBookingForm)

Comment: Use the debugger. Detect destruction. Perhaps `OnDestroy`, or an overridden `Destroy`.

Comment: The form onDestroy Method only gets called when the application is closed as expected. I can't find anywhere else it is being destroyed. This code works fine in XE4

Comment: Double free errors often seem to work, that's their nature. Since only you can debug, you'll have to do the rest. I've told you all that can be discerned from here. Now it's over to you.

Comment: Thanks for your help, Should l mark this answer as correct because I agree with you that it is being freed somewhere before we use it?

Comment: I don't know. I can't see what more we can do. I think you need to debug your problem.